# How do I force TeX to completely use the 1st column?

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

How do I force TeX to completely use the 1st column before writing to the second column?

Right now I dont have enough content to fill one whole page. So the left and right columns are equally filled, leaving 25% symmetrical empty page at bottom. How do I fill the left column first, and then the right?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{\tiny$\blacksquare$}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}    

%lots of text goes here

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See documentation of multicol, section 2.2 Not balancing the
columns.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use the starred variant of the `multicols` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{2}    
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 24):

As mentioned by Ulrike and Werner the way to stop `multicols` from balancing is to use the `multicols*` environment instead. But from the form of your question and your MWE I wonder if a simpler answer may not be: do not use `multicols` at all.

After all

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
```

or

```
\twocolumn[Some single column material] ...
```

will also get you two columns which aren't balanced and additionally work with floats in a more general fashion.

Basically you need to use `multicol` if you want one or more of these:

- balance columns (at least sometimes)
- switch between different column layouts on a single page (requires balancing obviously)
- use more than 2 columns on a page
- pagewide footnotes below the columns

But it comes at a price so if nothing of the above is what you are interested in then maybe you should simply remove the `multicol` package.

Comment: `multicol` is also useful to draw a vertical line between the columns. `multicol` can also draw the vertical line with a specified color and thickness.