# Multicols: use all vertical space before moving to a new column

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I force TeX to completely use the 1st column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53657/how-do-i-force-tex-to-completely-use-the-1st-column)

I am using a three-columns template to create cheat sheets:

```
\begin{multicols}{3}
...
\end{multicols}
```

When there is not much text, the result is divided equally between the three columns:

[image]

I would prefer having the entire text on the left column, exploiting the entire page height, e.g.:

[image]

How do exploit the full page height for the first column with `multicols`?

Comment: Can somebody with the right privileges add the `multicols` and `pagination` tags, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See package documentation of `multicol`: ["2.2 Not balancing the columns"](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tools/multicol.pdf#page=3):

```
\begin{multicols*}{3}
...
\end{multicols*}
```