# Make multicols use whole column in latex

Tags: multicol

I am trying to make a multicolumn layout. However, the content which I have is small. So it doesn't fill the whole page. Multicol somehow splits the content so the amount of content in the two columns are even. I don't want that. I want the content to be in the first column as much as it can accumulate rather than breaking it even into two columns

Comment: You're probably looking for [How do I force TeX to completely use the 1st column?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53657/5764) The suggestion is to use `multicols*`.