# Can I control the position of the column break within a two-column TOC?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, two-column, multicol, columnbreak

This is a follow-up question to [Splitting TOC into two columns on single frame in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24343/17423).

I have the following:

```
\begin{frame}{Questions}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
```

which is giving me

[image: output]

I'd really like to avoid splitting between subsections.  Can this be done?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}
\section{Problem Definition}
\subsection{Terminology}
\subsection{Naive Workflow}
\subsection{Fatal Problem}
\section{Current Solution}
\subsection{What we have}
\subsection{How we use it}
\section{How it Works}
\section{How to Build}
\section{Troubleshooting}
\subsection{No defaulting}
\subsection{Inconsistent defaulting}
\subsection{Most other problems}

\begin{frame}{Questions}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \tableofcontents
  \end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split the `toc` manually:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usetheme{default}

\begin{document}
\section{Problem Definition}
\subsection{Terminology}
\subsection{Naive Workflow}
\subsection{Fatal Problem}
\section{Current Solution}
\subsection{What we have}
\subsection{How we use it}
\section{How it Works}
\section{How to Build}
\section{Troubleshooting}
\subsection{No defaulting}
\subsection{Inconsistent defaulting}
\subsection{Most other problems}

\begin{frame}{Questions}
    \begin{columns}[onlytextwidth,T]
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections=1-2]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections=3-5]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is stealing the tick since it's a solution that's more easily changeable and seems to be how Beamer was designed to work – but here's a follow-up question: using [the same patch to visually group sections](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333917/17423), I'm getting some [very strange spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPavB.png). Any idea what's causing it? I may indeed ultimately use the second answer because of this, hacky/clever as it is.

Comment: @SeanAllred Thanks for the tick! I had a look at the other question, not really sure why your solution does not work with the code from this answer.

Answer (score 4):

[`multicols`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicols) doesn't allow for using the starred version of the environment which would [remove balancing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53657/5764).

You can decide the splitting manually by placing markers inside your document structure.

Below I define two `\if`-conditions: `\iffirsthalf` and `\ifsecondhalf`, knowing that you want to split it into two halves. Then, you can set `\firsthalftrue` and `\secondhalffalse` if you just want the first marked set of the ToC, or `\firsthalffalse` and `\secondhalftrue` if you want the second marked set:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\let\Tiny\tiny% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764

\usetheme{default}

\newif\iffirsthalf
\newif\ifsecondhalf

\begin{document}

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\iffirsthalf}% Start of first half...
\section{Problem Definition}
\subsection{Terminology}
\subsection{Naive Workflow}
\subsection{Fatal Problem}
\section{Current Solution}
\subsection{What we have}
\subsection{How we use it}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\fi% ...end of first half
                    \protect\ifsecondhalf}% Start of second half...
\section{How it Works}
\section{How to Build}
\section{Troubleshooting}
\subsection{No defaulting}
\subsection{Inconsistent defaulting}
\subsection{Most other problems}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\fi}% ...end of second half

\begin{frame}{Questions}
  \begin{columns}[T]
    \begin{column}{.4\linewidth}
    \firsthalftrue\secondhalffalse
    \tableofcontents
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.4\linewidth}
    \firsthalffalse\secondhalftrue
    \tableofcontents
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very clever :-)